# Not sure TypeError: fecha.createChoice is not a function myFunction?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I am using App script on a google form. What i am trying to do is update a Multiple choice questing with new dates changing it daily.  This is the code

```
function myFunction() {
const MILLIS_PER_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
const now=new Date();

var form = FormApp.openById('1jCbUFuCfKsPXTn9W5szndMEwBT05jDR_K8cFXPrtCz0');

var dt = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "MM/dd/yyyy")

var dt6 = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(now.getTime() - MILLIS_PER_DAY), "GMT+1", "MM/dd/yyyy")
var dt7 = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(now.getTime() - (MILLIS_PER_DAY*2)), "GMT+1", "MM/dd/yyyy")
var dt8 = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(now.getTime() - (MILLIS_PER_DAY*3)), "GMT+1", "MM/dd/yyyy")
var dt9 = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(now.getTime() - (MILLIS_PER_DAY*4)), "GMT+1", "MM/dd/yyyy")
var dt10 = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(now.getTime() - (MILLIS_PER_DAY*5)), "GMT+1", "MM/dd/yyyy")
pers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/choice
//Crear pregunta
var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
    
var formul = form.getItems();

  var ite = form.getItemById(1385844031);
  Logger.log( formul[3].getType());
   ite.setChoices([
          fecha.createChoice(dt10),
          fecha.createChoice(dt9),
          fecha.createChoice(dt8),
          fecha.createChoice(dt7),
          fecha.createChoice(dt6),
          fecha.createChoice(dt),

    ])

    
}

    enter code here
```

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether you have miscopied your script, it seems that in your showing script, `fecha` is not declared. How about this?

Comment: Thanks for answering, while modifying i forgot about changing that, but i still receive the same error with the code like this
   ite.setChoices([
          
          ite.createChoice(dt9),
          ite.createChoice(dt8),
          ite.createChoice(dt7),
          ite.createChoice(dt6),
          ite.createChoice(dt),

    ])

 This is the error
TypeError: ite.createChoice is not a function
myFunction @ date.gs:43

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a modification point as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direct solution to your issue, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

From your initial script, when I saw your showing script, `fecha` is not declared. And, from your following reply,

> while modifying i forgot about changing that, but i still receive the same error with the code like this ite.setChoices([ ite.createChoice(dt9), ite.createChoice(dt8), ite.createChoice(dt7), ite.createChoice(dt6), ite.createChoice(dt), ]) This is the error TypeError: ite.createChoice is not a function myFunction @ date.gs:43

In this case, if it can suppose that other parts except for `ite.setChoices([ ite.createChoice(dt9), ite.createChoice(dt8), ite.createChoice(dt7), ite.createChoice(dt6), ite.createChoice(dt), ])` are the same with your showing script, I thought that the reason of your issue is due to `ite`.

And, from `What i am trying to do is update a Multiple choice questing with new dates changing it daily.`, in your situation, I thought that the item of `var ite = form.getItemById(1385844031);` might be the multiple-choice item.

If my understanding is correct, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var ite = form.getItemById(1385844031);
Logger.log( formul[3].getType());
 ite.setChoices([
        fecha.createChoice(dt10),
        fecha.createChoice(dt9),
        fecha.createChoice(dt8),
        fecha.createChoice(dt7),
        fecha.createChoice(dt6),
        fecha.createChoice(dt),

  ])
```

#### To:

```
var ite = form.getItemById(1385844031).asMultipleChoiceItem();
ite.setChoices([
  ite.createChoice(dt10),
  ite.createChoice(dt9),
  ite.createChoice(dt8),
  ite.createChoice(dt7),
  ite.createChoice(dt6),
  ite.createChoice(dt),
]);
```

Or, if you want to use `formul[3]` of `var formul = form.getItems();` and that is the multiple-choice item, how about the following modification?

```
var ite = formul[3].asMultipleChoiceItem();
ite.setChoices([
  ite.createChoice(dt10),
  ite.createChoice(dt9),
  ite.createChoice(dt8),
  ite.createChoice(dt7),
  ite.createChoice(dt6),
  ite.createChoice(dt),
]);
```

#### References:

- [asMultipleChoiceItem()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item#asmultiplechoiceitem)
- [Class MultipleChoiceItem](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/multiple-choice-item)

Answer (score 0):

I tried the choices in a loop.

But, getting error Exception: The parameters (String,FormApp.Item) don't match the method signature for FormApp.ListItem.createChoice.
updateForm  @ Code.gs:103

item.createChoice is not a function

```
 //add go to page logic for Q9
  var formList = FormApp.ItemType.LIST;
  var formItems = form.getItems(formList);
  var item=formItems[0];
  var pgList = FormApp.ItemType.PAGE_BREAK;
  var pgItems = form.getItems(pgList);  
  Logger.log(pgItems[0].getTitle())
  Logger.log(item.getTitle())
  Logger.log(item.getType())
  //formItems[0].asListItem().setChoiceValues(multipleChoices);
  //formItems[0].asListItem().setChoiceValues([""]);//remove all list items
  //var multipleChoices=[]
  var choices = []
  for (i=1;i<qvals.length;i++){
    var pageBreakItem = pgItems[i];
    choices.push(item.createChoice(qvals[i][0]+" "+qvals[i][1],pageBreakItem));
  }
  item.setChoices(choices)
```